# Django - MultipleChoiceField is being displayed as a string instead of a list

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a MultipleChoiceField forms field (associated with a models CharField) which shows up in the database [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvBB2.png).  It seems to have been converted to a string in the database, because when I try to display it with a 'for property in property_type' statement in the HTML, it shows up [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnSFc.png).  I want it to be displayed [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3tHU.png)

So I have to write some code to fix this issue.  My pseudocode will look something like:

```
for record in property_type:
    split record at comma
    for i in record:
        if record[i] is not a letter or number:
            remove record[i]
```

Now my question is, where do I write this code?  Do I write it in the views.py or in the HTML file?  I tried doing it in views but I don't know how to select a single database record.  I tried doing it in the HTML but I was limited by the template tags.

Here is the shortened version of my code:

models.py:

```
property_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="You can select more than 1 option")
```

forms.py:

```
property_type = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple, choices=BuyerListing.PROPERTY_TYPE)
```

HTML:

```
    {% for property in listing.property_type %}
    <p>Property type: {{ property }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
```

EDIT:

Got it to work thanks to @ytsejam and @Daniel Roseman.  With ytsejam's code, the result will show up like this:

```
['1' '2']
```

I added a basic regex to ytsejam's code to remove the brackets and quotes:

```
def split_properties(self):
    a = self.property_type
    a = re.sub(r'[\]\[\']', '', a)
    a = a.split(',')
    return a
```

Now the list will display like this, which is very easy to manipulate in HTML.

```
1 2
```

Comment: You should fix the way the data is stored first of all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry where did I make a mistake with the way the data is stored?

Comment: The field is seemingly stored in the database as a list.  E.g ['hi', 'bye'].  But when I try to display the list in the HTML with a for loop, it gets displayed 1 digit at a time, which means it is actually a string rather than a list.

How do I convert the value to a list before displaying it on the HTML?

Comment: As I said, you should not save it by directly calling `str` on a list, but by doing `','.join(value)`; now you can simply call `value.split(',')` to get back a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `models.py`

```
 def split_properties(self):
        return self.properties.split(',')
```

and in your template use

```
{% for property in className.split_properties %} {{ property }} {% endfor %}
```